# How to make image scale to the size of div [ReactJS TS]

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

I am currently working on a admin panel that must display a list of videos / text links on cards.

The environment that I'm working on does not use bootstrap, so I could not simply use their cards. Which meant that I had to recreate the card components.

I have made it so the cards display normally as if it is a regular card as follow:
[image]

The code for this is:

```
<div className="">
        <Link className="styledLink" to={`adminhelpcard/${this.state.id}`}>
          <div className="card">
            <h5 className="card-header">{this.state.title}</h5>

            <div>
              <img
                className="Sprite"
                onLoad={() => this.setState({ imageLoading: false })}
                onError={() => this.setState({ tooManyRequests: true })}
                src={this.state.thumbnail}
                style={
                  this.state.tooManyRequests
                    ? { display: "none" }
                    : this.state.imageLoading
                    ? { display: "null" }
                    : { display: "null" }
                }
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              {this.state.tooManyRequests ? (
                <h6 className="mx-auto">
                  <span className="badge badge-danger mt-2"></span>
                </h6>
              ) : null}
              <div className="card-body mx-auto">
                <h6 className="card-title">
                  {this.state.title
                    .toLowerCase()
                    .split(" ")
                    .map((letter) => letter.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + letter.substring(1))
                    .join(" ")}
                </h6>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Link>
      </div>
```

I am trying to re-create the horizontal card (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/card/#horizontal)

for specifically the links containing videos. But it comes out like so

[image]

The code for the recreated attempt is as follows:

```
<div className="horizontalCard">
          <div className="innerCard">
            <div className="leftImage">
              <img
                className="Sprite"
                onLoad={() => this.setState({ imageLoading: false })}
                onError={() => this.setState({ tooManyRequests: true })}
                src={this.state.thumbnail}
                style={
                  this.state.tooManyRequests
                    ? { display: "none" }
                    : this.state.imageLoading
                    ? { display: "null" }
                    : { display: "null" }
                }
              />
            </div>
            <div className="rightText">
              <div className="card-body">
                <h5 className="card-title">{this.state.title}</h5>
                <p className="card-text">...</p>
                <p className="card-text">...</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

So my main question, is how can I go about recreating this / adjusting the image size so that it stays within the dimensions of the leftImage div.

Comment: The first step is to make sure that your image and text content align in a row. You can do this with floats, flexbox, or grid layouts. After that, it's a matter of (likely) capping how much horizontal space you want your image to take up. Then apply responsive CSS properties to the image (usually includes something like `{ max-width: 100%; height: auto;`).

Comment: @hungerstar Hey, thank you for the suggestion. When I change the max-width to 100% and height to auto, the image re-scales to much larger, making the whole div expand in size

Comment: The container element of the image needs a width as the image will scale to as large as it is allowed. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/x3atquyr/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With height: auto you can fit an image with respect to the aspect ration.

```
img.Sprite {
  display: block;  /*optional*/
  width: 100%;     /*optional*/
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 0;    
}
```

The parent of the img must have a width (in %, px, em, rem, or whatever)

Comment: So this actually has made it much better, but the only issue now is on the left side of the image, it extends outside of the card, rather than staying within it's rounded corners. Is there a way to sort this?

Comment: If the card has rounded corners, give the img the same border-radius. Leave out margin, padding and border from the image and card and look if it is better. If so, use other sizes.